# Sudo command in bash script halts the script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have an early 2009 iMac with a sensor problem. The ODD and CPU fans run at full speed. To get them down to minimum speed in Ubuntu I need to set the speeds in the Terminal, using [this method](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1565635). Rather than do this after every boot, I made a bash script to do it for me, but it doesn't work.

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Beginning script..."
echo "Logging in as root..."
sudo su
cd /sys/devices/platform/applesmc.768/
echo "Enabling manual override for Fan 1 (ODD fan)..."
echo '1' > fan1_manual
echo "Setting speed of Fan 1 (ODD fan) to 1650 RPM..."
echo '1650' > fan1_output
echo "Enabling manual override for Fan 3 (CPU fan)..."
echo '1' > fan3_manual
echo "Setting speed of Fan 3 (CPU fan) to 1200 RPM..."
echo '1200' > fan3_output
echo "Done."
```

The problem is at "sudo su". It prompts for a password, but after entering the password, nothing happens. It just halts.

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeyfp.png)

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70859/why-doesnt-sudo-su-in-a-shell-script-run-the-rest-of-the-script-as-root)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script halts because `sudo su` starts a new shell process. Your original shell process - the one that is running your script - is waiting for the sub-shell to end.

I propose to run whole script with root privileges instead of asking to log in as root from script itself. Remove `sudo su` part from your code and run script like that:

```
$ sudo ./yourscript
```

This is common practice. Note, that system administration scripts like for example `update-grub` don't ask for root password - they are just expected to be run as root.

Answer (score 4):

You could just take out the interactive stuff and copy the lines to `/etc/rc.local` between the 
**# By default this script does nothing.** and the **exit 0** lines

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

Insert the edited script..

```
cd /sys/devices/platform/applesmc.768/
echo "Enabling manual override for Fan 1 (ODD fan)..."
echo '1' > fan1_manual
echo "Setting speed of Fan 1 (ODD fan) to 1650 RPM..."
echo '1650' > fan1_output
echo "Enabling manual override for Fan 3 (CPU fan)..."
echo '1' > fan3_manual
echo "Setting speed of Fan 3 (CPU fan) to 1200 RPM..."
echo '1200' > fan3_output
```

<kbd>Ctl</kbd> o <kbd>Enter</kbd>    Will save the file

<kbd>Ctl</kbd> x                     Will exit nano

This way it'll execute when you boot.

Answer (score 0):

The command `sudo su` creates a new shell session. It is waiting for you to type your commands. It is **NOT** going to execute the commands after that line.

You have 2 options:

1) Extract the commands after `sudo su` in a separate script and run that with sudo

2) change the lines like `echo '1' > fan1_manual` to  `echo '1' | sudo tee fan1_manual`