# Do something in terminal that involve changing user

Tags: permissions, users, scripts, privileges

I want do something in terminal that involve changing user like:

```
sudo su
do something
do something
exit
do something
do something
sudo su
do something
do something
exit
```

I've tried to do something that need root's privelege like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo su
mkdir -pv /mnt/directory
exit
```

but it didn't work. The `mkdir` command is not done by root. It gives me message "permission denied" because the script run not in root.

Is it possible to do something like this? If yes, how?

**EDIT**

I'm sorry if my question is not clear. What I mean is make the script changing user in background with just inputting password once for all the commands that need root priveleges. Adding `sudo` for every command that need root priveleges is not what I mean.

Comment: Just sudo the script.

Comment: @Virusboy Sudoing the script pause what the script done in `sudo su` and then continue the task after I manually exit root login. The `mkdir` command still not done in root login.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/575626/sudo-command-in-bash-script-halts-the-script for an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prepend `sudo` to all the commands. Make sure to run the script as root, the unprivileged user will be put in as needed

```
#/bin/bash
do-something-neat                           # Run as invoking user (root)
sudo -u randomuser do-something-else        # Run as "randomuser" user
make potato --type=Mashed                   # Run as invoking user (root)
./servePotato.sh                            # Run as invoking user (root)
sudo -u randomuser eat MashedPotato.o       # Run as "randomuser" user
sudo -u fishy echo "I wanted potato!"       # Run as "fishy" user
```

Comment: I'm sorry if my question is not clear. What I mean is make the script changing user in background with just inputting password once for all the commands that need root priveleges. Adding `sudo` for every command that need root priveleges is not what I mean.

Comment: @BagolDaplun sudo will remember the password for a few minutes. Unless the script takes a lot of time, you shouldn't need to input password more than once.

Comment: @BagolDaplun updated.